# xml findtext extract all elements

Tags: python

My xml data base is like this :

```
<dict>
  <word id="">
    <sense>
        <ids></ids>
        <defs></defs>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <ids></ids>
        <defs></defs>
    </sense>
  </word>
</dict>
```

I want to extract all the senses of a given word A, this is my code:

```
dic = etree.parse("data.xml")
for word in dic.xpath("/dict/word"):
  MA = word.get("id")
  if MA == u'قطار':
    for elemt in word.findtext('sense/defs'):
        definition = elemt
         MonFichier.write(definition.encode("utf-8"))
```

The problem is this code writes only the last sense, not all the senses of a given word. This is the first time I'm using python, and I couldn't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question 100%, but you could try something like this:

```
words = etree.parse("data.xml").findall(u'.//word[@id="قطار"]')
for word in words:
    for elemt in word.findall('sense/defs'):
        MonFichier.write(elemt.encode("utf-8"))
```